# Delete rows in CSV based on specific value

Tags: python, csv

I want to delete specific rows in my CSV with Python. The CSV has multiple rows and columns.

```
import numpy as np

np.df2 = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/.../Data.csv', delimiter='\t')

np.df_2=np.df2[['Colum.X', 'Colum.Y']]
```

Python should open Data.csv and then delete every (complete) rows where the value of Colum.X > 5 or the value of Colum.Y > 20 in Data.csv.

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure what you're doing with `np.df2`, but the following will work:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/.../Data.csv', delimiter='\t')

df2 = df[(df['X'] <= 5) & (df['Y'] <= 20)]
```

You might have to add  `columns=['X', 'Y']` to the read_csv call, depending on what your CSV data looks like.

You can then overwrite the original file with:

```py
df2.to_csv('C:/Users/.../Data.csv')
```

Comment: This does the opposite of the question, and keeps the rows he wants to delete...

Comment: Fair comment. Amended.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this with Pandas, no need for Numpy. I assume the columns in your csv are actually named `'Colum.X'` and `'Colum.Y'`.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/.../Data.csv', delimiter='\t')
df = df.loc[df['Colum.X'] <= 5] # Take only the rows where Colum.X <= 5
df = df.loc[df['Colum.Y'] <= 20] # Take only the rows where Colum.Y <= 20 
df.to_csv('C:/Users/.../Data.csv', index=False) # Export back to csv (with comma's)
```